# Is there a legitimate use for void*?

Tags: c++

Is there a legitimate use of `void*` in C++? Or was this introduced because C had it?

Just to recap my thoughts:

**Input**: If we want to allow multiple input types we can overload functions and methods, alternatively we can define a common base class, or template (thanks for mentioning this in the answers). In both cases the code get's more descriptive and less error prone (provided the base class is implemented in a sane way).

**Output**: I can't think of any situation where I would prefer to receive  `void*` as opposed to something derived from a known base class.

Just to make it clear what I mean: I'm not specifically asking if there is a use-case for `void*`, but if there is a case where `void*` is the best or only available choice. Which has been perfectly answered by several people below.

Comment: how about the time when you want to have multiple types like int & std::string?

Comment: @Amir , `variant`, `any`, tagged union. Anything which can tell you actual type of content and safer to use.

Comment: "C has it" is a strong enough justification, no need to look for more. Avoiding it as much as possible is a good thing in either language.

Comment: Jut one thing: interop with C-style API's is awkward without it.

Comment: An interesting usage is [type erasure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450159/type-erasure-techniques/28695691#28695691) for vectors of pointers

Comment: C++ reduced the usefulness of `void*` (compared to `char*`) a lot when it removed the implicit conversion that C has. There is a good reason why malloc returns `void*` and not `char*`, and C++ completely missed it.

Comment: Note that K&R C did *not* have a `void` keyword.  Originally malloc returned type `char*`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use a void pointer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025579/when-to-use-a-void-pointer)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

`void*` is at least necessary as the result of `::operator new` (also every [`operator new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new)...) and of `malloc` and as the argument of the placement `new` operator.

`void*` can be thought as the common supertype of every pointer type. So it is not exactly meaning pointer to `void`, but pointer to anything.

BTW, if you wanted to keep some data for several unrelated global variables, you might use some `std::map<void*,int> score;`  then, after having declared global `int x;` and `double y;` and `std::string s;` do `score[&x]=1;` and `score[&y]=2;` and `score[&z]=3;`

[`memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset)  wants a `void*` address (the most generic ones)

Also, POSIX systems have [dlsym](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html) and its return type evidently should be `void*`

Comment: That's a very good point. I forgot to mention that I was thinking more from a language user rather than implementation side. One more thing I don't understand though: Is new a function? I thought of it more as a keyword

Comment: new is an operator, like + and sizeof.

Comment: Of course memory could be returned through a `char *` too. They're very close on this aspect, though the meaning is a bit different.

Comment: @Joshua. Didn't know that. Thank you for teaching me this. Since `C++` is written in `C++` this is reason enough to have `void*`. Gotta love this site. Ask one question learn a lot.

Comment: There is a keyword, a `new` expression, and an `operator new` all of which are distinct things.

Comment: @black Back in the old days, C didn't even _have_ a `void*` type. All standard library functions used `char*`

Answer (score 28):

There are multiple reasons to use `void*`, the 3 most common being:

1. interacting with a C library using `void*` in its interface
2. type-erasure
3. denoting un-typed memory

In reverse order, denoting un-typed memory with `void*` (3) instead of `char*` (or variants) helps preventing accidental pointer arithmetic; there are very few operations available on `void*` so it usually require casting before being useful. And of course, much like with `char*` there is no issue with aliasing.

Type-erasure (2) is still used in C++, in conjunction with templates or not:

- non-generic code helps reducing binary bloat, it's useful in cold paths even in generic code
- non-generic code is necessary for storage sometimes, even in generic container such as `std::function`

And obviously, when the interface you deal with uses `void*` (1), you have little choice.

Answer (score 16):

Oh yes. Even in C++ sometimes we go with `void *` rather than `template<class T*>` because sometimes the extra code from the template expansion weighs too much.

Commonly I would use it as the actual implementation of the type, and the template type would inherit from it and wrap the casts.

Also, custom slab allocators (operator new implementations) must use `void *`. This is one of the reasons why g++ added an extension of permitting pointer arithmatic on `void *` as though it were of size 1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You're right I forgot to mention templates. But wouldn't templates be even better suited for the task since the rarely introduce a performance penalty?(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442358/do-c-templates-make-programs-slow)

Comment: Templates introduce a code size penalty, which is also a performance penalty in most cases.

Comment: `struct wrapper_base {}; template<class T> struct wrapper : public wrapper_base {T val;} typedef wrapper* like_void_ptr;` is a minimal void-*-simulator using templates.

Comment: @Joshua: You're going to need a citation for "most".

Comment: @Mehrdad: See L1 cache.

Answer (score 11):

> Input: If we want to allow multiple input types we can overload
>   functions and methods

True.

> alternatively we can define a common base
>   class.

This is partially true: what if you *can't* define a common base class, an interface or similar? To define those you need to have access to the source code, which is often not possible.

You didn't mention templates. However, templates cannot help you with polymorphism: they work with static types i.e. known at compile time.

`void*` may be consider as the lowest common denominator. In C++, you typically *don't* need it because (i) you can't inherently do much with it and (ii) there are almost always better solutions.

Even further, you will typically end up on converting it to other concrete types. That's why `char *` is usually better, although it may indicate that you're expecting a C-style string, rather than a pure block of data. That's why`void*` is better than `char*` for that, because it allows implicit cast from other pointer types.

You're supposed to receive some data, work with it and produce an output; to achieve that, you need to know the data you're working with, otherwise you have a different problem which is not the one you were originally solving. Many languages don't have `void*` and have no problem with that, for instance.

### Another legitimate use

When printing pointer addresses with functions like `printf` the pointer shall have `void*` type and, therefore, you may need a cast to `void`*

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is as useful as any other thing in the language.
As an example, you can use it to erase the type of a class that you are able to statically cast to the right type when needed, in order to have a minimal and flexible interface.

In [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34154202/simple-event-system-in-c/34154876#34154876) response there is an example of use that should give you an idea.
I copy and paste it below for the sake of clarity:

```
class Dispatcher {
    Dispatcher() { }

    template<class C, void(C::*M)() = C::receive>
    static void invoke(void *instance) {
        (static_cast<C*>(instance)->*M)();
    }

public:
    template<class C, void(C::*M)() = &C::receive>
    static Dispatcher create(C *instance) {
        Dispatcher d;
        d.fn = &invoke<C, M>;
        d.instance = instance;
        return d;
    }

    void operator()() {
        (fn)(instance);
    }

private:
    using Fn = void(*)(void *);
    Fn fn;
    void *instance;
};
```

Obviously, this is only one of the bunch of uses of `void*`.

Answer (score 4):

Interfacing with an external library function which returns a pointer. Here is one for an Ada application.

```
extern "C" { void* ada_function();}

void* m_status_ptr = ada_function();
```

This returns a pointer to whatever it was Ada wanted to tell you about. You don't have to do anything fancy with it, you can give it back to Ada to do the next thing. 
In fact disentangling an Ada pointer in C++ is non-trivial.

Comment: Couldn't we use `auto` instead in this case? Assuming that the type is known at compile time.

Comment: Ah, nowadays we probably could. That code is from some years ago when I made some Ada wrappers.

Comment: Ada types can be devilish - they make their own, you know, and take a perverse pleasure in making it tricky. I was not allowed to change the interface, that would have been too easy, and it returned some nasty stuff hidden in those void pointers. Ugh.

Answer (score 2):

In short, C++ as a strict language (not taking into account C relics like *malloc()*) requires void* since it has no common parent of all possible types. Unlike ObjC, for example, which has *object*.

Comment: `malloc` and `new` both return `void *`, so you would need if even if there was an object class in C++

Comment: malloc is relict, but in strict languages *new* should return object *

Comment: how do you allocate an array of integers then?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev `operator new()` returns `void *`, but the `new` expression does not

Comment: 1. I'm not sure I'd like to see a *virtual* base class object above every class *and type*, including `int` 2. if it's non-virtual EBC, then how is it different from `void*`?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that occurs to my mind (which I suspect is a concrete case of a couple of the answers above) is the capability to pass an object instance to a threadproc in Windows.

I've got a couple of C++ classes which need to do this, they have worker thread implementations and the LPVOID parameter in the CreateThread() API gets an address of a static method implementation in the class so the worker thread can do the work with a specific instance of the class. Simple static cast back in the threadproc yields the instance to work with, allowing each instantiated object to have a worker thread from a single static method implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In case of multiple inheritance, if you need to get a pointer to the first byte of a memory chunk occupied by an object, you may `dynamic_cast` to `void*`.